# Make Text of One Div Same as Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone know how to copy the text of one div into another?

My situation is that I want to make a textbox that can have information typed into it and then show up in a div.

this is my code:

```
$("#title").text() = $("#t").text();
```

"#t" is my textbox and "#title" is the div.

The answer can be in javascript or jquery I don't mind. However I'd prefer jquery.

Comment: Seems to me, this is a simple RTFM issue. See here http://api.jquery.com/text/ ;-) -- `$("#title").text($("#t").text());` should work.

Comment: $("#title").text( $("#t").text());?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily done it like this by handling 'onkeyup' event of the input text.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div>
   <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
  </div>
  <div>
   <p id="typed-result"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt1').on('keyup',function(){
     var result = $(this).val();
     $('#typed-result').text(result);
    
    });
    
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the text entered go into the `src` of a `<image>` tag instead?

Comment: Actually you should post a new question for that. Anyway change the <p> tag with <img> tag and update the line of script that assign its 'src' attribute with this `$('#img1').attr('src',result);`

Comment: Is `result` supposed to be written out, or should i put a var there?

Comment: the `var result` was declared just to be seen clearly, you can just directly use $('#txt1').val() to get the text value inside the textbox.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, sorry!

Comment: Awesome! I got it figured out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132965/discussion-between-dimylute-and-emmet-arries).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
$("#title").text($("#t").val());
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#copyBtn").on("click", function(){
        $("#first").text($("#txtBox").val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">This is the div.</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter value" id="txtBox"/>
<input type="button" value="Copy text box value to div" id="copyBtn"/>
```

Comment: I'll have a look at how my code works and give a more indepth description

Comment: Well I'm stupid. I forgot to give the #gt id to my textarea... works now thanks!

Comment: @FinleySherwood I updated the snippet. You might need use the val for getting the value of the text box.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
 $('#getDiv').text($(this).val());
```

Try with this working example , just type something in textarea

```js
$(function(){

  $('#getText').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#getDiv').text($(this).val());
  })

});
```

```html
<textarea id="getText"></textarea>

<div id="getDiv"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but with a dropdown menu instead of a text box?

Comment: Is there a way to make the text entered go into the `src` of a `<image>` tag instead?

Comment: @EmmetArries , i don't get you question , can you tell me more clearly

Comment: Thank you, but I got it answered. See the comments under this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41585167/5892719

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$("#t").keyup(function(){ 
   $("#title").text($("#t").value()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) JavaScript event, Something like this -

HTML -

```
<body>
  <input type='text' id='one'>
  <div id='two'></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#two').text($(this).val());
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtArea').keyup(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();  
   $('.txt-block').text($("#txtArea").val());
  // #txtArea is ur textarea box where you type text.
  // .txt-block is your div where textarea Text shows.
});
```

Comment: A bit more of a description around your answer would be nice. Also, there's no point having the `event.preventDefault()` here as the key press has already happened and there's nothing to stop (not that you'd want to stop it anyway).